# Why is this endpoint getting a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Tags: javascript, cors, axios, fastapi

I'm struggling to understand why this request is giving me a CORS error.  I believe I have both the server and client setup to consume the endpoint properly.  I can make the same request with postman and it works, so I think there is something I'm doing wrong with JS.  The server is using Fastapi, a python framework.  The client is Vue but the request uses Axios (which is Javascript).  Any insight would be appreciated.

Server Settings

```
app = FastAPI(title="OptionStrats",
    description="For fun fin-trial",
    version="0.0.1",)

origins = ["*", "http://localhost:8080/"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Client Request

```
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "http://optionstrats.com/backtest",
  headers: {
    common: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  data: request_dict,
  crossDomain: true
})
.then(response => {
  console.log("backtest response", response);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Logs

```
Starting Request 
Object { url: "http://optionstrats.com/backtest", method: "post", data: {…}, headers: {…}, transformRequest: (1) […], transformResponse: (1) […], timeout: 0, adapter: xhrAdapter()
, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
Backtest.vue:464
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://optionstrats.com/backtest. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Error: "Network Error"
createError createError.js:16
handleError xhr.js:81
```

I'm explicitly including Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the axios request headers but it seems to not be understood.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: the error shows that you are trying to access http://optionstrats.com/backtest not http://localhost:8080

Comment: _“I'm explicitly including Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the axios request headers but it seems to not be understood.”_ - CORS does not seem to be understood so far - by _you_. This is a header that needs to be set in the _response_; sending it with the _request_ makes zero sense to begin with.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Yea I misunderstood what it was asking of me.  I'll try correcting it this way.

Answer (score -1):

The error you mentioned is a server side error and cannot be fix in client side. it's a header value which comes from the server response.

Access control is a security technique that can be used to regulate who or what can view or use resources in a computing environment.

The header needs to be set on the server you are trying to access to allow you to do this.

> Browsers send specific HTTP headers for cross-site requests initiated
>   from within XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch API. They also expect to see
>   specific HTTP headers sent back with cross-site responses. An overview
>   of these headers, including sample JavaScript code that initiates
>   requests and processes responses from the server, as well as a
>   discussion of each header, can be found in the HTTP Access Control
>   (CORS) article and should be read as a companion article to this one.
>   This article covers processing Access Control Requests and formulating
>   Access Control Responses in PHP. The target audience for this article
>   are server programmers or administrators. Although the code samples
>   shown here are in PHP, similar concepts apply for ASP.net, Perl,
>   Python, Java, etc.; in general, these concepts can be applied to any
>   server-side programming environment that processes HTTP requests and
>   dynamically formulates HTTP responses.

enabling CORS in apache would be like

```
RewriteRule ^/api(.*)\.json$ /api$1.json [CORS=True]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=CORS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET" env=CORS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "false" env=CORS
```

every language has it's own configuration. so you can search about "how to enable cors in 
 web api" or any other language.

*For enabling CORS in FastAPI try to look at this document:*

https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/main.py#L20-L26